# How to use CURL command inside Jenkins for retrieving status code?

Tags: linux, curl, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am using CURL command in jenkins for retrieving "status code" of an ip.
I did the following command in terminal and it is working properly.

**curl -i ip_address:port**

Output of terminal

**HTTP/1.1 200 OK**

But in the case of jenkins,

I added the above command inside "Execute shell"
It is the giving error with the following output.

**curl -i ip_address:port**

% Total     % Received    % Xferd    AverageDload    Speed Upload  TimeTotal

0           0             0            0                0       --:--:--
   TimeSpent    TimeLeft   CurrentSpeed

--:--:--        --:--:--       --:--:--
curl:
Failed to connect to ip_address port : Connection refused

Can anyone suggest a solution for the same?

Comment: Does it work when you run `curl` yourself from a terminal on Jenkins server? If not, you should ask your network administrator why the connection is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a Jenkins question/answer but try this:

```
curl -i -s IP:port/path
```